# Trying to make an html checkbox which adds a number to an output field

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-table

I am trying to create a table in which when I check a box, if the image displayed is yes.jpg, a number gets added in the output box at the bottom of the column. If not, no number gets added. There are three columns, and each checkbox affects three images and so three output boxes. Here is my code.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script>
     function onSelect(rowId)
     {
        var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
        var checkBox = row.getElementsByTagName("checkRow")[0];
        var outputRow = document.getElementById("outputRow");
        var totalRow1 = outputRow.getElementById("total1");
        var totalRow2 = outputRow.getElementById("total2");
        var totalRow3 = outputRow.getElementById("total3");
        //If box is checked, check images. If they are yes, edit boxes. 
        if (checkBox.checked)
            if (row.getElementById.("image1").src.indexOf(yes.png) > -1)
            {
                totalRow1.innerHTML = "dfd";
            }
        else {
            //checkBox = 
            }
        }
         /*function onCheck()
        {
            var total1 = document.getElementById("total1");
            window.alert("sometext");
            total1.innerHTML = "dfd";
        } */
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr> <!-- Table Header -->
            <td>
                Checkbox
            </td>
            <td>
                Items
            </td>
            <td>
                Area 1
            </td>
            <td>
                Area 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Area 3
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="checkRow"> <!-- Row 1 -->
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Row1" value="Row1" onclick="onCheck();">
                </form>     
            </td>
            <td>
                Item
            </td>
            <td id="image1">
                <img src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
            </td>
            <td id="image2">
                <img src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
            </td>
            <td id="image3">
                <img src="no.png" alt="Needed">
            </td>   
        </tr>



        <tr id="outputRow"> <!-- Table Bottom -->
            <td>
                <!--Empty-->
            </td>
            <td>
                Summation
            </td>
            <td id="total1">
                Area 1
            </td >
            <td id="total2">
                Area 2
            </td>
            <td id= "total3">
                Area 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Currently, I am just trying to edit the output text on one of the output boxes (as seen in my `onCheck()` method). However, even this does not seem to work. I added an alert, which does not happen either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("checkRow")[0]` . I don't see any `<tags>` named checkRow.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of errors like `onSelect` vs. `onCheck` and not passing in the argument to the function.  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?  I don't think I understand.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many things, you are doing wrong,

firstly, you have called `onCheck()` function upon click on your checkbox, but there is not such javascript function. you have `onSelect(id)` instead.

second, you are trying to `.getElementById` your `TDs` as those ids, 'image1' and all are ids of tds and not imgs

and then you are accessing `.src` for them, so anyway that is wrong.

Improvements:

1. change your input checkbox to this:

   ```
    <input type="checkbox" name="Row1" value="Row1"  onchange="onCheck(this);">
   ```

what you are doing is that, you are passing reference of your input in the function onCheck(this);

`2`. now change your markup like this:

```
     <td>
            <form>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Row1" value="Row1"  onchange="onCheck(this);">
            </form>     
        </td>
        <td>
            Item
        </td>
        <td >
            <img  id="image1" src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td >
            <img id="image2" src="yes.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>
        <td >
            <img  id="image3" src="no.png" alt="Needed">
        </td>   
    </tr>
```

all i've done is to provide IDs to the right elements i.e. to the IMGs, instead of TDs;

thirdly, make your onCheck() like this:

```
function onCheck(cb)
         {
            if(cb.checked===true)
            {
                if(document.getElementById('image1').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                    document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML='555';
                } 
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('total1').innerHTML='No';
                }

                if(document.getElementById('image2').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                    document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML='555';
                } 
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('total2').innerHTML='No';
                }

                if(document.getElementById('image3').src.toString().indexOf('yes')>0){
                    document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML='555';
                } 
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('total3').innerHTML='No';
                }  
            }
        }
```

so basically onCheck is pretty much same as your one.

now , see this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/GGxpX/), i've made for you, it works. ofcourse I hate the way you are doing it all. This all can be done in a much easier way.

also, learn about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it makes life easy.